# Generalised Fortunate Prime Sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

The primorial \$p_n\#\$ is the product of the first \$n\$ primes. The sequence begins \$2, 6, 30, 210, 2310\$.

A [Fortunate number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number), \$F_n\$, is the smallest integer \$m > 1\$ such that \$p_n\# + m\$ is prime. For example \$F_7 = 19\$ as:

$$p_7\# = 2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17 = 510510$$

Adding each number between \$2\$ and \$18\$ to \$510510\$ all yield composite numbers. However, \$510510 + 19 = 510529\$ which is prime.

Let us generalise this to integer sequences beyond primes however. Let \$\Pi(S,n)\$ represent the product of the first \$n\$ elements of some infinite sequence \$S\$. All elements of \$S\$ are natural numbers (not including zero) and no element is repeated. \$S\$ is guaranteed to be strictly increasing.

In this case, \$p_n\# = \Pi(\mathbb P,n)\$. We can then define a new type of numbers, generalised Fortunate numbers, \$F(S,n)\$ as the smallest integer \$m > 1\$ such that \$\Pi(S,n) + m \in S\$.

You are to take an integer \$n\$ and an infinite sequence of positive integers \$S\$ and output \$F(S,n)\$.

You may take input in any reasonable representation of an infinite sequence. That includes, but is not limited to:

- An infinite list, if your language is capable of handling those (e.g. Haskell)
- A [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/66833) which returns the next element of the sequence each time it is queried
- A black box function which returns two distinct values to indict whether it's argument is a member of that sequence or not
- A black box function which takes an integer \$x\$ and returns the \$x\$th element of the sequence

If you have another method you are considering using, please ask in the comments about it's validity.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Examples

I'll walk through a couple of examples, then present a list of test cases below.

**\$n = 5, S = \{1, 2, 6, 24, 120, ...\}\$**

Here, \$S\$ is the [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) from 1. First, \$\Pi(S, 5) = 1\times2\times6\times24\times120 = 34560\$. We then find the next factorial greater than \$34560\$, which is \$8! = 40320\$ and subtract the two to get \$m = 40320 - 34560 = 5760\$.

**\$n = 3, S = \{6, 28, 496, 8128, ...\}\$**

Here, \$S\$ is the set of [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). First, \$\Pi(S, 3) = 6\times28\times496 = 83328\$. The next perfect number is \$33550336\$, so \$m = 33550336 - 83328 = 33467008\$

### Test cases

```
n
S
F(S, n)

5
{1,2,6,24,120,...} (factorials)
5760

3
{6,28,496,8128,...} (perfect numbers)
33467008

7
{2,3,5,7,11,...} (prime numbers)
19

5
{1,3,6,10,15,...} (triangular numbers)
75

Any n
{1,2,3,4,...} (positive integers)
2

9
{1,4,9,16,25,...} (squares)
725761

13
{4,6,9,10,14,...} (semiprimes)
23
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ḟ>1M<¹Π↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5v9aipMffcAj9TEOPIhgJziMBiiICfCUT40bSFlod3/H@4Y76doa/NoZ3nFjxqm/j/PwA) (Missing the testcase for perfect numbers because it was too slow, and the one for semiprimes because implementing the list of semiprimes is a challenge itself)

Takes as input `S` and `n`, where `S` is an infinite list.

#### Explanation

```
ḟ>1M<¹Π↑
       ↑     Take the first n elements from S
      Π       and get their product
   M ¹       For each element x in S
    <         subtract the product if it is smaller than x, return 0 if it is bigger
ḟ            Find the first element in this list
 >1           that is greater than 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev), 70 bytes

```
n=>s=>{p=[...Array(n)].reduce(a=>a*s(),1);while((x=s()-p)<1);return x}
```

Can't access TIO on my school network. I'll post a link soon!

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 83 bytes

```scala
s=>n=>{val p=s.take(n).product;Stream.from(2)find(m=>s takeWhile(p+m>=_)toSet p+m)}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QJqQgNCZTtSOP4c25kAKsg)

Takes an infinite `LazyList`.

If outputting the product + m had been allowed, I could've used a few evil syntax-bending tricks for 71 bytes, but this is a lot more boring.

```
s=>Stream.from(2)map s.take(_).product.+find(? =>s takeWhile?.>=toSet?)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eFQwND4XSFmyeWvDXR6cHg)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

```javascript
(S,x=1)=>f=n=>n?f(n-1,x*=S()):(t=S()-x)>0?t:f()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BDoIwEETvfMkuFEKtEKTZEi7cCUdjDEGqGNIaaQx/X@vdw2Tm8F7mOX7GbXovL5cae5t9Rx4GthNHUpoMKdNoMClne0wDINbgfp3uqPLG1RrQy6glLvuQaLJms@ucrfYOHVxJtTH1SYJQIMoocOeSHSp2PJWs4mEIURS5EOXln5ptj0W78Aki2P4L)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes non-recursive

```javascript
S=>n=>{for(x=1;e=S(),e<=(x*=n--<1||e););return e-x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvBCoJAFADvfkXH93RXsk0x1id48S4eI0JqLUN2Y7UQsm/f9gM6DMxh5tG9u@lih@fMtbkqV5NrqdRUfnpjYaFEKmoBmSoIlpA050WyrgolSqvml9UbxZevk0Hl08YTXIyezKji0dyghjOVVUhNFCGkiDLw3TFju5ztDxnLEy9CpOlWiOz0b42n@9DPgAjC3@4H)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 58 bytes

```clj
#(nth(for[i % j[(- i(apply *(take %2%)))]:when(< 1 j)]j)0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BasMwEETv/oqBYFi5BJpCD036J0IH1V47cpWVI69T8vWu4kJpr/MGZl4b07hkXqnjHv26I9Ez9SnbgBqjpT0C@WmKdzSk/pNRv9TGGHf8OrPQOw4YjRvNs1lNRV2a@QprBYrBwVYnTGkOGm6MIMoD57myb7j4CaFj0aB3h9Kar4vP/Mt21JT12mys962mHHws@BWZu6XVkGRG4wrVQmRYos@Q5fKxDfxrPbnK4RhZYdsUI6hcAwXl7PXxqsWh6LiKplwuRsGPpuDRNuZP3m8RpOiv3w)

Takes input as a lazy sequence and a number \$n\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 36 bytes

```
1 :'([(-~u)>:@]^:(>:u)^:_)~[:*/u@i.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNC4JAEIbv@yumLrqh29q66zqgSEGn6NBVKqRWsuiDSAgC/7qNNTAw7zMzz7kfC6@GDMGDACQgdShgsVkt@wjQ80s/7FqeY7HdoZ9jy3e4512Jk2lbNMLrOVvPBVyri4PmBTJsbkf3dkdWV4dXJmBU5Mjc4XQHnRgJGQwcatBvRvVwz5qOfBPMbBCnJrARDUppLZWipG1qTSq14Z9u@9coFZtESkuq4ZtUilS/VZQOEAklrP8C)

This is an adverb modifying the sequence generator, which is assumed to be 0-indexed and which returns the nth element.

It just increments the input n until f(n) > relevant product to find the number to subtract from.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
£P-.Δ1›
```

First input is \$n\$, second input is an infinite sequence \$S\$.

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC6KOOeUUxemEuEf8PLQ7Q1Ts3xfBRw67/tTr/o6OV0hKTS/KLMhNzipV0lBSVdExjdRSilQpSi9JSk0sU8kpzk1KLQFKnJrkcnnhohX9grZKOEURNUWZuKoqKAqCcOViuBGhiXnppTmIRigILLbvDrYc21cKtyS/OLMksS1XIzCtJTYeoUtIxNABLFheWJhalgoTylHQsIUKpuZlgayHGHZ6UbgM0yyQ2FgA) or [try it online with 05AB1E code as additional input to generate the infinite sequence](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX/4oiewrIuVkTCuf/Co1AtLs6UMeKAuv//NQoh). (The perfect numbers and semiprimes test cases have been lowered to \$n=2\$ and \$n=4\$ respectively, because they time out for \$n=3\$ and \$n=13\$ on TIO.)

**Explanation:**

```python
£        # Leave the first (implicit) input `n` amount of leading items from the second
         # infinite input-list `S`
 P       # Take the product of these first `n` values
  -      # Subtract it from each item in the second infinite input-list `S`
   .Δ    # Pop and leave the first value which is truthy for:
     1›  #  Check that it's larger than 1
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```